# How to pull changes from develop branch in PhpStorm?

Tags: git, version-control, phpstorm

I am still relatively new to both PhpStorm and Git. Without leaving the IDE, I want to pull changes from the `develop` branch into a feature branch.

I've gathered that <kbd>Command-T</kbd> (on a Mac) brings up the "Update project" dialogue box, which is what I should be using. But I'm lost after that point, since I don't understand what any of the options presented in that dialogue box do.

On the command line, I would simply type `git fetch` and then `git pull origin develop`. How do I do the equivalent here, using the GUI?

Comment: Please see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/sync-with-a-remote-repository.html#update. You might want to check other related articles on this webhelp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go to **VCS** > **Git** > **Pull**. Then in **Branches to merge** you can select develop to merge the **develop** branch on the one you're currently on.

The best things to do is to set up a keymap on the **Pull** action to avoid the clicks.

You can also invoke the **Pull** window by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> and writing **pull**.

Hope it did the job. :)

Answer (score 1):

You may not see your branch under the Pull drop-down in PhpStorm.
In that case, 1st try a git fetch. This will update your remote branches records.
Then you can pull by selecting the newly added branch of your remote repo.